# Increase execution time for MySql delete query

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I need to remove duplicate rows in table by some value and leave only 1.
i use this query

```
DELETE n1 FROM cities_extended n1, cities_extended n2 WHERE n1.city_id > n2.city_id AND n1.city = n2.city
```

but my table has about 65000 rows, and execution takes too long and i have no idea how to speed up this.

Comment: Use a transaction.

Comment: If that is not it, perhaps your mysql needs to be better tuned. A lot of distributions ship with very unoptimal default settings for a modern PC.

Comment: a multi column index (city_id, city) on both tables should help

Comment: @RaymondNijland can you give an example of query please? city_id is PK by the way, it's just some errors where 1 city was added twice or more.

Answer (score 2):

Making sure all of the fields in the where clause are indexed. If any of them are not indexed Running this query will index them.

```
ALTER TABLE cities_extended ADD INDEX `city` (`city`)
```

If this hasn't been indexed, it will definitely speed up the query.

You could also try using a temp table.

```
drop table if exists `temp_for_duplicates`
CREATE TABLE `temp_for_duplicates` AS select * from `cities_extended` where 1 group by [field with duplicates]

truncate table `cities_extended`

INSERT INTO `cities_extended` SELECT * FROM `temp_for_duplicates`
```

Comment: They are indexed i guess city_id is PK and it's unique, but there is gaps like city_id (1-100,200-205,1000-2000)

Comment: How long is it taking? How much faster do you need it to be? You could insert the data into a temp table using a group by for the field that has duplicates and then truncate your table and then re-instert the existing data back into the table. This will remove all duplicates.

Comment: i've aborted it after 15 mins of no results, i guess if there is no other way i'll try tmp table.

Comment: 15 mins is way to long. Using a temp table would take around 10 seconds. Maybe less.